# Are any of these protein stabilization papers prior art for this patent?

Tags: prior-art, chemistry-microbiology, us20100190188

MUTANT G-PROTEIN COUPLED RECEPTORS AND METHODS FOR SELECTING THEM
Patent application [12/450,358](http://www.google.com/patents/us20100190188) filed Mar 20, 2008

Here is an example of engineering mutants to give better thermostability of a protease.  Essentially the methods are the same as the ones in this patent(different kind of activity assay) http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3145814

Here is a version of this type of engineering from back in 1994 http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7950371

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of the documents you cited on PubMed qualify as prior art under 35 USC 102(b); they were published more than one year before the effective filing date of application 12/450,358.

Whether the claims would be rejected over the teachings of these documents is a different question, which will have to be answered by the examiner to which the application is assigned.

Comment: Whether the claims would be rejected is in fact a question we try to answer here. We can't give a definitive answer, of course (and even patent offices in different jurisdictions may decide differently), but at least to the extent of whether it would be worth submitting the document as potential prior art.